# Is there a way to filter that does not include duplicates/repeated entries by particular groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, data-manipulation

Some context first:
I'm working with a data set which includes health related data. It includes questionnaire scores pre and post treatment. However, some clients reappear within the data for further treatment. I've provided a mock example of the data in the code section.

I have tried to come up with a solution on dplyr as this is package I'm most familiar with, but I didn't achieve what I've wanted.

```
#Example/mock data
   ClientNumber<-c("4355", "2231", "8894", "9002", "4355", "2231", "8894", "9002", "4355", "2231")
        Pre_Post<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1)
        QuestionnaireScore<-c(62,76,88,56,22,30, 35,40,70,71)
        df<-data.frame(ClientNumber, Pre_Post, QuestionnaireScore)
        df$ClientNumber<-as.character(df$ClientNumber)
        df$Pre_Post<-as.factor(df$Pre_Post)
        View(df)
```

```
#tried solution
df2<-df%>%
  group_by(ClientNumber)%>%
  filter( Pre_Post==1|Pre_Post==2)
#this doesn't work, or needs more code to it
```

As you can see, the first four client numbers both have a pre and post treatment score. This is good. However, client numbers 4355 and 2231 appear again at the end (you could say they have relapsed and started new treatment). These two clients do not have a post treatment score.

> I only want to analyse clients that have a pre and post score, therefore I need to filter clients which have completed treatment, while excluding ones that do not have a post treatment score if they have appeared in the data again. In relation to the example I've provided, I want to include the first 8 for analysis while excluding the last two, as they do not have a post treatment score.

Comment: Could you paste what your expected data should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to create groups of 2 for every `ClientNumber` and select only those groups which have 2 rows in them.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(ClientNumber) %>%
  group_by(ClientNumber, group = cumsum(Pre_Post == 1)) %>%
  filter(n() == 2) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

#  ClientNumber Pre_Post QuestionnaireScore
#    <chr>        <fct>          <dbl>
#1    2231         1               76
#2    2231         2               30
#3    4355         1               62
#4    4355         2               22
#5    8894         1               88
#6    8894         2               35
#7    9002         1               56
#8    9002         2               40
```

---

The same can be translated in base R using `ave`

```
new_df <- df[order(df$ClientNumber), ]
subset(new_df, ave(Pre_Post,ClientNumber,cumsum(Pre_Post == 1),FUN = length) == 2)
```

Comment: The dplyr solution works very well. I like how it orders the clients in a way which allows inspection of pre and post on top of each other, which is really convenient. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First `arrange` ClientNumbers then `group_by` and finally filter using `dplyr::lead` and `dplyr::lag`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(ClientNumber) %>% group_by(ClientNumber) %>% 
       filter(Pre_Post==1 & lead(Pre_Post)==2 | Pre_Post==2 & lag(Pre_Post)==1)

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   ClientNumber [4]
   ClientNumber Pre_Post QuestionnaireScore
   <fct>           <dbl>              <dbl>
1 2231                1                 76
2 2231                2                 30
3 4355                1                 62
4 4355                2                 22
5 8894                1                 88
6 8894                2                 35
7 9002                1                 56
8 9002                2                 40
```

Comment: This also worked a treat. What I like about this solution is that it ordered the rows in a way which allowed me to inspect to inspect pre and post results upon each other; very helpful for eye-balling the data. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If these cases are to be kept in order, you could try:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ClientNumber) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(Pre_Post) & n_distinct(Pre_Post) == 2)

  ClientNumber Pre_Post QuestionnaireScore
  <fct>           <dbl>              <dbl>
1 4355                1                 62
2 2231                1                 76
3 8894                1                 88
4 9002                1                 56
5 4355                2                 22
6 2231                2                 30
7 8894                2                 35
8 9002                2                 40
```

I don't know if you actually need to use `n_distinct()` but it won't hurt to keep it. This will remove cases who have a pre score but no post score if they exist in the data.

Comment: This worked very well. It preserved the order and appears to have removed the ClientNumbers that I was looking to remove. Thank you very much!